# How to automate queries to download data from a website with python

Tags: python, database, download, automation

I am trying to download some data from https://www.eddmaps.org/tools/query/
I need to select certain criteria and create a loop to download data for 67 counties in Florida.

So far I was only able to sign in to website. Tried to use libraries such as beautifulsoup and selenium but could not figure it out

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.eddmaps.org/tools/index.cfm?forcelogin&'
values = {'username': 'myuseername',
          'password': 'mypasword'}
r0 = requests.post(url, data=values)


url2 = 'https://www.eddmaps.org/tools/query/'
r1 =requests.get(url2)

print(r1.status_code == requests.codes.ok)
```

It seems I need to know more than python. Please help if this can be achiavable

Comment: You should be able to try one query, then view the URL and update it according to the other queries `https://www.eddmaps.org/tools/query/results.cfm?reporter=&userGroupID=&observationDateStart=1%2F1%2F2019&observationDateEnd=5%2F31%2F2019&dateEnteredStart=&dateEnteredEnd=&dateUpdatedStart=&dateUpdatedEnd=&objectid=&subjectnumber=1024&cat=&div=&eradicationstatus=&list=&rank=&habitat=&country=926&state=&fipscode=&township=&layersourceid=&project=` can be parsed down by each `=` into the fields in the search form. Try one or two manually and see which elements change.

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you! I will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to login, then make the query, then download the data. You might need to use the `session` feature in requests:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
url = 'https://www.eddmaps.org/tools/index.cfm?forcelogin&'
login_data = {'username': 'myuseername',
                  'password': 'mypasword'}
res1 = s.post(url, login_data)
try:

    res1.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    print('login failed')

# Make a query
url2 = 'https://www.eddmaps.org/tools/query/results.cfm?reporter=&userGroupID=&observationDateStart=&observationDateEnd=&dateEnteredStart=&dateEnteredEnd=&dateUpdatedStart=&dateUpdatedEnd=&objectid=&subjectnumber=&cat=&div=&eradicationstatus=2&list=&rank=&habitat=&country=926&state=&fipscode=&township=&layersourceid=&project='
res2 = s.get(url2)
try:    
    res2.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    print('query failed')
```